# Python: Find starting, ending index of sub-text column from another text column

Tags: python, pandas, nlp-question-answering

I am trying my hand at Question Answering and have to make my own dataset. I have 5 columns:

```
question | context | answer | answer_start | answer_end
```

Each record in the `context` column has a chunk of text, e.g.,

> Neil Alden Armstrong (August 5, 1930 – August 25, 2012) was an American astronaut and aeronautical engineer, and the first person to walk on the Moon. He was also a naval aviator, test pilot, and university professor.

The corresponding `answer` contains a string of text extracted from the `context`, e.g.,

> the first person to walk on the Moon

I need to populate `answer_start` and `answer_end`, which are the starting/ending indexes of the `answer` text within `context`. In the above example, `answer_start` would be 114 & `answer_end` would be 150. They are currently empty columns.

I tried the following:

```
df['answer_start'].apply(lambda x: re.search(x['answer'], x['context']).start())
```

But it threw an error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Is there a way to fix what I have? Is there a way to do this that doesn't require a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df['answer_start'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['context'].find(x['answer']), axis=1)
df['answer_end'] = df['answer_start'] + df['answer'].str.len()
```

```
>>> df[['answer_start', 'answer_end']]
   answer_start  answer_end
0           113         149
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `df.apply` instead of `df['answer_start'].apply`. Because you are using apply on a series what you get as an x is not a row but an integer number

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but then got  "KeyError: variableName"

Comment: you should also change the axis to 1 like `df.apply(your_function, axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'context': 
                   ['The cat sat on the mat', 'Around the world we go'],
                   'answer': ['mat', 'world']})


df['answer_start'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['context'].find(x['answer']), axis=1)
df['answer_end'] = df['answer'].str.len() + df['answer_start']

print(df)

                  context answer  answer_start  answer_end
0  The cat sat on the mat    mat            19          22
1  Around the world we go  world            11          16
```

Comment: `len(df['answer'])` returns the number of rows not the length of the string in the cell

Comment: Doh, fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `context` and `answer` fields to calculate the indices. to use multiple fields you should use `df.apply`. For example I have created a toy dataset:

```py
import pandas as pd

text = "this is text number"

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [f"{text} {i+1}" for i in range(4)], "B": text.split(" ")})
```

The data looks as follows:

```
                       A       B
0  this is text number 1    this
1  this is text number 2      is
2  this is text number 3    text
3  this is text number 4  number
```

Now we can calculate the `start` and `end` index values:

```py
df["start"] = df.apply(lambda row: row["A"].find(row["B"]), axis=1)
df["end"] = df.apply(lambda row: row["start"] + len(row["B"]), axis=1)
```

And this is the result:

```
                       A       B  start  end
0  this is text number 1    this      0    4
1  this is text number 2      is      2    4
2  this is text number 3    text      8   12
3  this is text number 4  number     13   19
```